# Heatmap with category values in seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data frame.

```
ID   Cat  V1 V2 V3
1     A    1  1  1
2     B    1  1  1
3     A    1  1  0
4     C    0  0  0
```

I want to create a plot (similar to a heatmap) that shows if V1 to V3 were observed (1) or not (0).
Furthermore, each field should be colored according to the category of the row.
For example, if `Cat` is A, it shall be red; if `Cat` is B, it shall be green; and if `Cat` is C, it shall be blue.
Hence,  in this case, all squares in the first row of the heatmap shall be red, and in the second row, they shall be green.

I want to use seaborn or matplotlib in python to create the plot.
However, I do not know what the type of plot would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there exist less involved ways. The following approach loops through the categories; for each category a heatmap is filled with the corresponding color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''ID   Cat  V1 V2 V3
1     A    1  1  1
2     B    1  1  1
3     A    1  1  0
4     C    0  0  0'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.set_index('ID')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']
colors = ['crimson', 'lime', 'dodgerblue']
for cat, color in zip(categories, colors):
    df_cat = df[['V1', 'V2', 'V3']][df['Cat'] == cat].reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
    df_cat[['V1', 'V2', 'V3']] = df_cat[['V1', 'V2', 'V3']].replace({0: np.nan})
    if not np.all(df_cat.isna()):
        sns.heatmap(data=df_cat, cmap=ListedColormap([color]), cbar=False, lw=1, alpha=1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap colored by first column]